# Can't copy to usb device

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, file-copy, fat32

Changed /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/usb rw,noatime,user,umask=0 0 0
```

Mounted

```
mount -a
```

But while copying showed

```
Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Make sure your user has permissions to use the USB. http://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives may help.

Comment: Set chown -R robot:robot /media/usb and chmod -R 777 /media/usb anyway don't copy

Comment: I think the option `umask=0` may be your issue, but I cannot remember why. The expected behavior of umask=0, is that everyone has full access, but some other security may stand in the way of that (SELinux AppArmor, Access Control List).

Answer (score 0):

Having the user, who is desired to be able to access the device, create the directory that it will be mounted to first, avoids the need to deal with permissions.

```
su SOME_USER -c 'mkdir -p /mnt/external'
```

*The `su` command can be avoid if logged in as SOME_USER.*

I recommend using the device's UUID as its identifier. Though labels also work well. The drive letter may change, especially for removable media.

I use a simple listing like the below for semi-permanent or frequent USB drives.

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/external xfs defaults 0 0
```

Two ways of figuring out the UUID:

- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`
- `blkid /dev/SOME_DEVICE`

  - example devices/partitions: `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/loop0` or `/dev/md3`

*The file-system type is also given by `blkid`.*

---

*Tested on CentOS 7.*